# Slider is not working broken logic javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am trying to make a slider. But for some reason i can't get the logic right. I know once in past i have gotten it right. But i don't remember it now.

**Updated**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/9QqNa/2/

```
var slider= $('.slider'), mY, dY, clicking=false;

slider.mousedown(function(e){
     mY = e.pageY, clicking = true;
})
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    if (!clicking) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    dY= e.offsetY-mY;
    mY +=dY;
    console.log(e);
    slider.css('top','+='+dY);
}).mouseup(removeit);

function removeit(){ 
    clicking=false; 
}
```

Problems Include: Updated
  - Need to stop at above and bottom limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a quick look at your code, simply change the follow line:

> dY= e.offsetY-mY;

to

> dY= e.pageY-mY;

this should do

Comment: yes i did that...there is other problem too look at my comment

Comment: @MuhammadUmer just checked the script again seems you'd solved it already, why put the `* {overflow: visible!important;}` in the css file?

Comment: i wanted to see what's happening...but you see it's not perfect. If you scroll to fast the slider actually breaks the limit and goes off bound. Improved version so please check it out http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/9QqNa/3/ ....also is there any library for this